# How to manage the scope in the symbol table

Tags: c, bison, symbol-table

I have to build a compiler that translates the java language into pyhton. I'm using the Flex and Bison tools. I created the flex file and I defined the syntactic grammar in Bison for some restrictions that I have to implement (such as the management of cycles, management of a class, management of logical-arithmetic operators, etc.).
As for semantic analysis, I have a problem with the symbol table. I'm using the uthash.h library to handle hash tables. For the moment I have created a simple symbol table composed only by the key and the name of the symbol. What I would like to understand, is how to manage the scope (portion of the program in which the declaration of the identifier is applied) with the symbol table and then how to identify a scope to be able to insert it in the symbol table.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks so much.

This is the module containing the basic structure of the symbol table and some functions:

```
#include "uthash.h" //http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html

struct symtable         
{
  int id;               // Key 
  char name[20];    
  UT_hash_handle hh;  /* makes this structure hashable */
};

struct symtable *symbols = NULL;

void add_symbol(int symbol_id, char *name) { 

  struct symtable *s;
  HASH_FIND_INT(symbols, &symbol_id, s); 
  if (s==NULL) {
    s = (struct symtable *)malloc(sizeof *s);
    s->id = symbol_id;
    HASH_ADD_INT( symbols, id, s );         
  }
  strcpy(s->name, name);

}

struct symtable *find_symbol(int symbol_id) {  

  struct symtable *s;
  HASH_FIND_INT( symbols, &symbol_id, s );      
  return s;

}

void delete_symbol(struct symtable *symbol) {   

  HASH_DEL(symbols, symbol);                
  free(symbol);

}

void delete_all() {                             

  struct symtable *current_symbol, *tmp;
  HASH_ITER(hh, symbols, current_symbol, tmp) { 
    HASH_DEL(symbols,current_symbol);           
    free(current_symbol);                       
  }

}

void print_symbol() {

  struct symtable *s;
  for(s=symbols; s != NULL; s=(struct symtable*)(s->hh.next)) {
     printf(" Symbol id %d: name %s\n", s->id, s->name);
  }

}
```

Comment: The short answer is that you need a symbol table (hash table) for each scope.

Comment: ... provided that you need this at all.  It's not immediately clear to me why you need to track symbol definitions to support your particular task.  That's not saying I'm confident you don't need it, but do be sure you know, in some detail, how and why you're going to use it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  When do I need to manage the scopes? Because this is actually the problem, I do not know if they should be managed. What I have to do is translate a java code (formed by the restrictions mentioned in the post) in pyhton. So for example there must be at least one class, one method, some iteration and some logical arithmetic operation.

Comment: I don't have a very satisfactory answer to that, @Michele.  The best I can do is: you need to track symbol definitions if your program's output must differ when the definitions differ.  If you have not identified any such scenarios yet, then I suggest putting the whole question on the shelf until you do.